# Java: how to put specific object attributes into an array by using a for loop

Tags: java

I want create an array with a for-loop that stores the user's pin, but I have absolutely no idea how to take specific attributes from an object in this manner.

```
public class Customers {

    private String first; 
    private String last; 
    private int pin; 

    public Customers(String fn, String ln, int p) {
        this.first = fn; 
        this.last = ln; 
        this.pin = p; 
        System.out.println(first + " " + last+ " Pin: " +pin);

    }
    public int getPin() {
        return pin; 

    }

}
```

---

```
public class MainMethod{

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Customers cust1 = new Customers("Tom", " Hardy", 9883);
        Customers cust2 = new Customers("Bob", "Dylan", 6543); 
        Customers cust3 = new Customers("Allen", "Williams", 5432);
        Customers cust4 = new Customers("Zack", "Wyld", 6543);
        Customers cust5 = new Customers("Derek", "Barker", 5424);

        Customers[] customerInventory = new Customers[5];
        customerInventory[0] = cust1;
        customerInventory[1] = cust2; 
        customerInventory[2] = cust3; 
        customerInventory[3] = cust4; 
        customerInventory[4] = cust5; 

    }
}
```

I have attempted different ways of going about this, but have had no luck.

Comment: "I have absolutely no idea how to take specific attributes from an object" - Can't you just call `getPin()` on the `Customer` instance?

Comment: I don't really get what you want to achieve here... fill an ´int[]´ with pins of all the users ? In that case, yeah.. call the getter, if you have one. And if you don`t, it isn't too surprising that you can't access an otherwise private field of your class

Comment: Step 1: loop over the customerInventory array to be able to do "something" with each customer in it. Surely you can research how to do that? Any chapter in a book or article on the web about a for loop will show how to do that.

Comment: I just typed this up quick because I need it in a few other applications. I'm used to python; new to java, but can't seem to create an array with specific object attributes--like the users pin. I can create arrays, I can create arrays that contain objects, but cannot create an array of specific object attributes. If anyone could post an example of how to do this, it would help tremendously!

Answer (score -2):

You already have a method which will return you the PIN for each Object. You just need to use the object with the method getPin().

```
public class MainMethod {
public static void main(String [] args) {

Customers cust1 = new Customers("Tom", " Hardy", 9883);
Customers cust2 = new Customers("Bob", "Dylan", 6543); 
Customers cust3 = new Customers("Allen", "Williams", 5432);
Customers cust4 = new Customers("Zack", "Wyld", 6543);
Customers cust5 = new Customers("Derek", "Barker", 5424);

int[] pin = new int[5];
pin[0] = cust1.getPin();
pin[1] = cust2.getPin(); 
pin[2] = cust3.getPin(); 
pin[3] = cust4.getPin(); 
pin[4] = cust5.getPin(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. `customerInventory` is an array of `Customer`s; `getPin()` is an `int`.

Comment: @Strikegently is it fine now?